# Splitting the JSON string resulting in null

Tags: javascript, jquery

The data I'm getting after posting a jQuery Ajax request is of the form

```
[{"name":"Man","id":"1"},{"name":"SKC","id":"2"},{"name":"fsdfds","id":"3"},{"name":"ETA","id":"4"},{"name":"Star","id":"5"},{"name":"SCity ","id":"6"},{"name":"TESTGB","id":"11"}]
```

So I need to split this in such a way that I get a dropdown like:

```
<select>
<option value="1">Man</option>
<option value="2">SKC</option>
.
.
.
</select>
```

I have tried this, but this splits the data into null.

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {                  
    $('#bu_group').append($('<option/>', { 
        value: value,
        text : value 
    }));
});
```

Comment: Are you actually getting that as a string, or is that just JavaScript code? JavaScript objects and JSON are not the same thing.

Comment: @Qantas 94 Heavy I'm getting this from jquery ajax response. In console it says string

Comment: Okay, I've removed the `var data=` bit to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$.each(data, function (index, val) {                  
                        $('#bu_group').append($('<option/>', { 
                            value: val.id,
                            text : val.name 
                        }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give this way:

```
$.each(data, function (index, data) {                  
    $('#bu_group').append($('<option/>', { 
        "value": data.id,
        "text": data.name
    }));
});
```

Or, the other way like you wanted both the value and text to be the same:

```
$.each(data, function (index, data) {                  
    $('#bu_group').append($('<option/>', { 
        "value": data.name,
        "text": data.name
    }));
});
```

The attribute `value` and the value `value` are conflicting. Moreover, you need to access the `value`'s inner members and not the `value` itself.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/zLELr/

Comment: @user3004356 Please check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/zLELr/

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourArray = JSON.parse(data);
                   console.log(yourArray);                                           
                    $.each(yourArray, function (index, yourArray) {                 
                        $('#builder_group').append($('<option/>', { 
                            value: yourArray.id,
                            text : yourArray.name, 
                        }));
});
```

This solved my problem